# Can't set CurrentRow/CurrentCell for DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Can you tell me how to prevent **CurrentRow** from staying null after following code executes:

```
private void Kartons_DataGrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Kartons_DataGrid.Rows)
            {
                Kartons_DataGrid.ClearSelection();
                var line = (TransportUnitHeader)row.DataBoundItem;
                if (line.NoTransportUnit == _selectTuNo)
                {
                    if (Kartons_DataGrid.CurrentRow != null) Kartons_DataGrid.CurrentRow.Selected = false;
                    Kartons_DataGrid.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;
                    Kartons_DataGrid.CurrentCell = Kartons_DataGrid.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0];
                    _selectTuNo = string.Empty;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

At line

```
Kartons_DataGrid.CurrentCell = Kartons_DataGrid.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0];
```

it always throws NullReference for CurrentCell, thus it cannot be changed.

I need first row of DataGridView to be selected by default after databinding is completed.

Comment: Why do it in the loop?? Add Kartons_DataGrid.CurrentCell = Kartons_DataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0]; but not without testing for null! - Also: Did you check in the debugger what is null in the line??

Comment: `Kartons_DataGrid.CurrentCell = Kartons_DataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0]` not possible because CurrentCell is always null, and that's the problem

Comment: Nonsense! this line __sets__ it, provided there __is a row and a cell__.

Comment: Ok, I watch it tomorrow and write back. Thanks

Comment: @TaW `Kartons_DataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0];` This call causes the nullreference exception, but I checked cell at index 0 and it has value. Suggestions? Error is in German, but it should translate to "Index -1 has no value" or something similar.

Comment: So there is a row at 0 and a Cell at 0? Then it can't be null. Check again! (Do it right when the exception is on the screen!)

Comment: @TaW Yes there is but error says "Index -1 does not have a value" Where does index -1 come from at all?

Comment: Nor is any value accessed in the line you mention. So it really can't be that line. Hard to help from here on; maybe add a screenshot of the exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the help of following thread: [DataGridView "index -1 does not have a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785307/datagridview-index-1-does-not-have-a-value)

In short, change List to BindingList as the datasource and that's it.